# ReactJS Concept of Virtual DOM

Tags: reactjs

> ReactJS lays on the concept of Virtual DOM. So where does it store the copy of Real DOM. In the system or somewhere else???

Answer (score 0):

"Real" DOM is handled by the browser, it's not up to the application to store the DOM.

With every change your make (props of some components are changed), React first renders your app into the virtual DOM, just so that it can compare this new virtual DOM to the previous virtual DOM and figure out the minimum set of changes it has to do to the real DOM in order to update it to match the current state.

When the actual DOM changes, browser also updates what user sees on the screen, but real DOM updates are pretty slow, so you want to do as little of them as possible.

See also MDN's [Introduction to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)